# qTip2: how to attach to head-element?

Tags: jquery, html, qtip2

I'm trying to attach my qTip2-script in the head-element of my html document, but it seems like I'm not getting it right.

I have written this so far:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

<script src="qtip.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qtip.css">
```

The complete code works fine in jsfiddle, but not when I try to copy everything to notepad++.

This is the jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/fdavn/

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the script url.  Try to use the exact path of the url. Such as the below.

```
'<script src="/Scripts/qtip.js"></script>'
```

If you are still having issues, double check to make sure that the following are referencing the current versions that you are using:

```
    <link rel="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
```

****UPDATED****

Verify the following:

HTML FILE:

```
<head>
<title>My New Site</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="qtip.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qtip.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#test" title="My tooltip text">Sample link</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#test2" title="My title.New">Sample Link 2</a>
</body>
```

qtip.css FILE: ("same folder as HTML file")

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

qtip.js FILE: ("Same folder as HTML file")

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a[title]').qtip();

});
```

Just tested it using the above files and it worked perfectly.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I feel like I have been trying all different kinds of versions and it's still not working. The jquery seems fine, I think it's the .css that's somehow missing but I can't figure out why.

Comment: the next question would be, are you using Visual Studio or any program to compile the site?

Comment: I have only used Notepad++ so far.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and recreate the issue later today.  So I can understand correctly, you only want to replace links with a precreated link?  Is that correct?

Comment: I just want it to work, that's all, cause I'm just confused why it doesn't work with what I already have written. If you can make it work in any kind of way, that's good for me.

Comment: If it doesn't/is not working with the code I pasted, then try using Visual Studio Web Express.  Create a new site, add the code I just supplied and it will work.  The issue may be that you don't have the javascripts installed to test that function out locally.